# Play (H264 - MPEG4 - AVC) live stream in browser

Tags: web, video, stream, video-streaming, media-player

I want to create a webpage with a video player that can play a (H264 - MPEG4 - AVC) live stream and the URL of streaming video doesn't include format in the end of URL.
Example "http://halowtv.online:8080/HalowTV/FSyzHfEhvb/137".
I can't find any web player that can do that.

I read that JWPlayer is capable of doing that, but only in the paid version.

The stream can be played in VLC and any other players.

What can I do? I tried using ffmpeg to convert the stream to something more useful, but no success.

Comment: Try searching for: [Javascript H264 player](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=javascript+h264+player). We can only help with existing code problems or a programming question like explaining code concepts.

Comment: @VC.One , I searched for that too much and tried about 15 players I didn't find, as you see I provide you a VALID streaming URL above, try to play it online if you can then tell me which player you choose, Thank you.

Comment: “ H264 - MPEG4 - AVC” isn’t enough information. What is the container type? Is there a manifest or playlist at that url?

Comment: No Sir this URL as is , VLC can play it.
but now I reached to the solution I can convert that URL to playlist and play it smoothly.
Thank you